# TYPO3 FAL translation fails in Extbase Extension

Tags: typo3, translate, fluid, extbase, fal

I'm using `TYPO3 7.6.14` and my Website is bilingual 'english' and 'japanese'. My editors translate all english content, also FAL-Metadata for images, like 'description', 'alt-text' and 'title', s. screenshot.
[image: FAL Metadata TYPO3 Language]

The whole page is translated, only the `FAL`-data from images fails (s. screenshot). I don't know why? Do anyone see my fault?
I am grateful for any help because I simply do not know what it is ...  Thanks.

Here's the TCA

```
...
'additional_information' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:products/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_products_domain_model_product.additional_information',
            'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
                'additional_information',
                array(
                    'appearance' => array(
                        'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
                    ),
                    'foreign_types' => array(
                        '0' => array(
                            'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ),
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => array(
                            'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                        )
                    ),
                    'maxitems' => 10
                ),
                $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
            ),
        ),
...
```

and the `Fluid`-Template (s. caption: `photo.originalResource.properties.description`)

```
<f:for each="{product.additionalInformation}" as="photo" iteration="iterator">
          <div class="column">
          <a class="lightbox2" href="{f:uri.image(src: photo.originalResource.publicUrl, width: 1024)}" data-lightbox="{product.uid}" title="{photo.originalResource.properties.description}">
          <f:image src="{photo.originalResource.originalFile.uid}" alt="" />
            <span class="caption">                                            {photo.originalResource.properties.description}</span>
             </a>
       </div>
</f:for>
```

Frontend Output:

[image: frontend FAL meta data]

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `<f:image src="{photo.originalResource.originalFile.uid}" alt="" />` with `<f:image image="{photo}" alt="" />`.

It can be that FAL translations a not properly supported. Please have a look at the `news` extension from Georg Ringer. If it is not working there, then it is not working at all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I was looking at News `FalMediaImage` we have `<f:image image="{mediaElement}"...` and `<p class="news-img-caption">{mediaElement.description}</p>` ... but I try ... `<f:debug>{photo.description}</f:debug>` == NULL, no image and not the right description.

Comment: If you have not image in photo, then you have another bug altogether.

Comment: `<f:debug>{photo.originalResource.publicUrl}</f:debug>` gives me the filename of the images. So I've thought `{photo.originalResource.properties.description}` for image description, and it works. But the translation handling is wrong. No japanese Image description is showing ..

Comment: If `{photo.originalResource}` is not null, then `{photo}` cannot be null either.

Comment: Hi pgampe .. I think there's a TYPO3-Bug. [https://forge.typo3.org/issues/57272] and the problem is still known ... aargh! I have to wait to `TYPO3 v8`  .. that's not good.

Comment: It is not fixed in 8 LTS.

Comment: that's a huge problem .. I know this FAL/Translation error from `tx_news`. So I don't translate the Data record and create two sys folders (en+jp).

Comment: At the moment you can use one folder. You need two separate data records for two languages. Do not fill out the field `original file` ('Ursprungstext'). Then it works. I hope the problem will be fix in `TYPO3 8 LTS`.